# Running install scripts during the pip install <package>

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, software-distribution

I'm trying to run a shell script that completes the installation and will be run when installing the package and not when preparing it

I've tried

```
def _post_install(dir):
    with open("/tmp/myfile", "w") as fh:
        fh.writelines(["after install: {}".format(distro.linux_distribution())])


class install(_install):
    def run(self):
        self.execute(_post_install, (self.install_lib,),
                     msg="Running post install task")
        _install.run(self)

setup (... 
install_scripts={'install': install}
)
```

and also

```
class PostInstallCommand(install):
    """Post-installation for installation mode."""
    def run(self):
        _post_install()
        install.run(self)


setup (... 
cmdclass={'install': install}
)
```

none works.

After running `pip install <pkgname>` I'm expecting to see the file `/tmp/myfile` with content, however this file doesn't exist

Comment: Please provide an error message if it is possible. There is no enough information provided to conclude some possible solutions.

Comment: Install command will be executed only when running `pip install <pkgname> --no-binary=<pkgname>`. It will not be executed on regular installs.

Comment: @s3nh, there is no error message. when I run `pip install <pkname>`  I expected to see the file `/tmp/myfile` with some context. I don't see it

Comment: @hoefling, how can I run install command or something else using regular installs?

Comment: I already posted the only possibility, by using `--no-binary` flag. Or download the sdist file, unpack it and run `python setup.py install` directly.